# How to create node for modulating color image with Python

Tags: node-editor

I am rendering with blender GUI, but I have to do some work with python in blender.
I want to take color image and modulate it (eg. edge detecting or fourier transform it) and save it.

I think I can make it with creating new node whose input is connected to color of render layer and output is connected to file output.

Is is possible to make this kind of new node?
Thank you in advance!